# nodejs-angular retrieving data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I have been trying to retrieve data from mongodb (i'm using also mongoose) and send it to angular to fill the ng-repeat list with data. I am able to print data on blank page from mongo OR display data in list if i declare exemplary static array with data in a list on webpage but i dont know how to connect it to work with data from mongo. I am new to MEAN stack so please spare me.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through video tutorial of Bucky Robert. Try to create the project from Hello world then you will understand.

Node JS tutorial [click here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_)

MEAN STACK tutorial: [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Avv-Y_ePYA0)

Comment: Thank you, i watched them but theyre not much helpful - first is only about node and second is indeed about mean and there are angular tutorials but in them he also uses arrays written in angular file, not data from database. And my problem is basically communication between node and angular

Answer (score 0):

First Create RestFul API using Node js 
http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/10/01/creating-a-restful-api-tutorial-with-nodejs-and-mongodb/

Then consume the same using following example.

```
MessageServiceData.getMessageService=function(){
        var def = $q.defer();
                $http.post("www.url.com", data)
                    .success(function(messages){
                         def.resolve(messages);
                     })
                    .error(function(messagesFail){
                        console.log('error:'+JSON.stringify(messagesFail));
                        def.reject([{"Error":JSON.stringify(messagesFail)}]);
                    });

        return def.promise;
    }
```